Hands On Iterable Variable For Loops in Salesforce
I used the guidance from Get Hands-On with an Iterable Variable in For Loops to create my test class, but I'm experiencing the following error when trying to validate my work: testIterableForLoop failed(), check Error message for more details.
Why is this happening? And why don't I see any debug logs? Thanks.

Have you checked the Trailhead Challenges discussion topic?
